# How to search for text inside decoded json data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to search for particular texts inside the data received from an API call using the response.body function with the http library in Flutter. I have decoded the data with jsonDecode(data) into a var called decodedData.

How can i search for particular field inside this decodedData?

Answer (score 0):

It's a map and you can use `containsKey` or `containsValue` to search for a particular text

Comment: I can only access the top level Key and Value using these functions. How do i access the nested Key and Value pairs of the Map?

Comment: `decodedData.map((key, value) => value.toString().contains('yourtext'))`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you  just want to search for a particular string from  whole body .then you can follow the steps Bellow

- Convert the response body to a string using .tostring() method.
- str1.contains('rem')

Use the .contains method to search for the dedired string

Comment: How do i iterate through the nested key value pairs in my decoded json Map to check for a condition?

Comment: If its a MAP you can iterate throught it using .where  method which accepts a condition and  returns the key value if condition satisfies.